# What should I do about Resharpers inspector hint 'Use of possibly unassigned property or global variable'?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, resharper

Take the following code as an example:

```
someFactory.someApiCall()
    .then(function () {
        //do something in a success case
    }, function (error) {
        if (error.data.Message) {
            $scope.error = "Failed: " + error.data.Message;
        }           
    });
```

Resharpers inspector gives me a warning about the use of `error.data.Message` 'Use of possibly unassigned property or global variable'.

Having searched around I am unsure what should be done to fix this if anything? It is a 'hint' level tip from Resharper however, in the editor (Visual Studio in my case) there is no distinction between levels of warnings and I don't want to get into the habit of ignoring things.

What would a fix of this be considering the error object is coming back from a api call?

**[UPDATE]**

I have also tried the following with the warning still appearing.

```
if (error && error.data && error.data.Message) {
    $scope.error = "Failed: " + error.data.Message;
}
```

and

```
if (error && error.data) {
    if (error.data.hasOwnProperty("Message")) $scope.error = "Failed: " + error.data.Message;
}
```

I am tempted to just disable the tip altogether but there are situations where it could be helpful...

Comment: My guess is that you're checking that `error.data.Message` exists but you're not checking that `error.data` exists: `if (error.data && error.data.Message)`...

Comment: unfortunately even doing a check of both still shows the hint. (Even this does - `if (error && error.data && error.data.Message) {`)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution than disabling this inspection altogether will be to disable it just once by a comment

```
// ReSharper disable once PossiblyUnassignedProperty
```

or in entire file

```
// ReSharper disable PossiblyUnassignedProperty
```